# Add an "Ease out" option to the animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this [JS animated counter](https://github.com/pablog1/js-animated-counter). At the moment there only seems to be two options for the animation - "linear" or "swing".

There seems to be very little JS defining this so it feels like I'm missing something. How can I make it ease out instead of using linear or swing?

From what I can tell this is the block that controls the easing:

```
function doCount(num, index, speed, groupClass, direction, easing) {
    let className = groupClass + ' ' + counterClass + '.' + 'c_' + index;
    if(easing == undefined) easing = "swing";
    $(className).animate({
        num
    }, {
        duration: +speed,
        easing: easing,
        step: function (now) {
            if (direction == 'reverse') {
                $(this).text(num - Math.floor(now));
            } else {
                $(this).text(Math.floor(now));
            }
        },
        complete: doCount
    });
}
```

The variable `easing` is just calling in the data attribute which is either set to linear by default or swing.

I've tried just adding "easeOut" but no luck with that hit and hope!!

Comment: Easing options were added to jQuery UI. https://jqueryui.com/easing/. Note however jQuery UI is pretty much a dead project

Comment: @j08691 Are linear and swing the only options available? Is there no way to add easing into the current setup?

Comment: If you visit https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/ and scroll down to the demo with the dropdown box you'll see a list available

Answer (score 2):

As highlighted in the comments above, jQuery by itself only supports two types of easing functions, `linear` and `swing`. This is outlined [here](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#easing) in the jQuery documentation, which also points out that you can add additional easing functions by including [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) in your project, this could be done by including the jQuery UI CDN in addition to the standard jQuery library:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-lSjKY0/srUM9BE3dPm+c4fBo1dky2v27Gdjm2uoZaL0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Once you've included jQuery UI, you can use the [easing functions it provides](https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/). There are a number of easing functions you can use, and you can find a list of each easing function and its implementation by logging the `$.easing` object. A list is also included in the docs:

```js
linear, swing, easeInQuad, easeOutQuad, easeInOutQuad, easeInCubic, easeOutCubic, easeInOutCubic, easeInQuart, easeOutQuart, easeInOutQuart, easeInQuint, easeOutQuint, easeInOutQuint, easeInExpo, easeOutExpo, easeInOutExpo, easeInSine, easeOutSine, easeInOutSine, easeInCirc, easeOutCirc, easeInOutCirc, easeInElastic, easeOutElastic, easeInOutElastic, easeInBack, easeOutBack, easeInOutBack, easeInBounce, easeOutBounce, easeInOutBounce
```

You can then use one of these easing functions for your counter, eg:

```html
<div class="counter" data-TargetNum="5" data-Speed="5000" data-Easing="easeOutQuad"></div>
```

See example below:

```html
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include jQueryUI -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-lSjKY0/srUM9BE3dPm+c4fBo1dky2v27Gdjm2uoZaL0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Include js-animated-counter (note: you should download and include the file locally rather than using this link) -->
<script src="https://pablog1.github.io/js-animated-counter/multi-animated-counter.js"></script>

<div id="counters_1">
  <h3>Linear:</h3>
  <div class="counter" data-TargetNum="5" data-Speed="5000" 
  data-Easing="linear"></div>
  <h3>Swing:</h3>
  <div class="counter" data-TargetNum="5" data-Speed="5000" 
  data-Easing="swing"></div>
  <h3>easeOutQuad:</h3>
  <div class="counter" data-TargetNum="5" data-Speed="5000" 
  data-Easing="easeOutQuad"></div>
</div>
```

Note that you don't need to include the entire jQuery UI library in your project and can instead select just the **Effects core** component for just the easing functions, which you can do on their download page [here](https://jqueryui.com/download/).

Answer (score 2):

The standard library only supports 2 options, `swing` and `linear`.
But **jquery UI** library supports many options for easing attribute. You can choose the below one.
`easeOutExpo`, `easeOutQuint`, `easeOutQuart`, `easeOutCubic`, `easeOutQuad` ...
Don't forget to import jquery-ui script.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You can check more options here with examples.
https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/